# How to connect an iPad 3 to 27" Apple Cinema Display (Mini DisplayPort)

Tags: ipad, displayport, cinema-display

How can I connect my iPad 3 (30-pin dock connector) to my 27" Cinema Display (MiniDisplayPort)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need 2 different adapters :

iPad 3 => Dock to HDMI adapter => HMDI to mini displayport => Cinema Display.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if, when connected in this way, the iPad will scale videos to the full size of the Cinema Display? Or will it be chopped off on each side?